# Improving boxplot readability

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Making boxplots for the flights data contained in the nycflights13 package I get the following boxplot.
[image]
Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(nycflights13)

attach(flights)

ggplot(flights, aes(x = "", y = dep_delay)) + 
  geom_boxplot(color="darkblue")
```

As shown in the image there are a lot of outliers which makes it hard to read anything else but these outliers.

Are there any methods/techniques to improve the readability of this plot?

Comment: Would something like `ggplot(flights, aes(x = "", y = asinh(dep_delay))) + 
  geom_boxplot(color="darkblue") ` work for you?

Comment: try to present the data with transformation of the `y`, perhaps `log10(dep_delay)` will be helpful

Comment: @M_Shimal There are values <= 0 present in the data set...

Comment: @dario what exactly does this do? As I see the outliers are missing now.

Comment: `?asinh` calls the [inverse hyperbolic sin function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions), we can use it sometimes as a replacement for `log` transformation with log-incompatible values

Comment: my bad, didn't check the data first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @dario, you could transform the y-axis scale.  The interquartile ranges (box range) will stay the same, but because the whiskers are defined as 1.5* the IQR, the definition of 'outlier' will differ according to the scale ... I found the `asinh()` transformation a little too extreme, so tried the signed-square-root transformation as well ...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(nycflights13)
library(cowplot)

tt <- scales::trans_new("asinh", transform=asinh, inverse=sinh)
ss <- scales::trans_new("ssqrt", transform=function(x) sign(x)*sqrt(abs(x)), inverse=function(x) sign(x)*x^2)

gg0 <- ggplot(flights, aes(y = dep_delay)) + 
    geom_boxplot(color="darkblue")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL)

plot_grid(nrow=1,
    gg0 + ylab("flight delay\n(original scale)"),
    gg0 + scale_y_continuous(trans=tt) + ylab("flight delay\n(asinh transform)"),
    gg0 + scale_y_continuous(trans=ss) + ylab("flight delay\n(signed sqrt transform)"))

ggsave("scale_boxplot.png")
```

[image]

Comment: If I apply the sqrt transform will this result in loss of information reading the plot? For example less point in the outliers.

Comment: IMO the main drawback of the scale transformation is that the uneven spacing of ticks may be unfamiliar to some readers, who may thus misinterpret the figure.  I don't think "fewer outlier points" is really a loss of information; the definition of outliers in boxplots (more extreme than IQR*1.5) is sensible but essentially arbitrary.

Comment: Any further thoughts about the presentation would be (1) probably opinion-based and (2) would really depend on the context: why are you drawing this figure in the first place, who is your audience, what is the main point you want to get across etc. ...

Comment: So that means its just a compression technique like log right?

Answer (score 3):

We have many options. But basically we can

Transform:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(nycflights13)

ggplot(flights, aes(x = "", y = asinh(dep_delay))) + 
  geom_boxplot(color="darkblue")
```

[image]

or use a different type of plot:

```
ggplot(flights, aes(x = "", y = dep_delay)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.7) +
  geom_jitter()
```

[image]

or transform and use a different type plot:

```
ggplot(flights, aes(x = "", y = asinh(dep_delay))) + 
geom_violin()
```

[image]

What the correct solution is depends heavily on the thing you want to illustrate with the plot (and the available data of course)

Comment: I like your plot options, but I would combine them with my scale transformations - few people looking at the plot will be able to interpret what asinh(departure delay)=-5 will mean ...

Comment: @Ben Bolker You are absolutely right, but I wanted to keep the answer to this rather complex problem of data visualization as general as possible. But a transformed y axis is definitely more readable and in almost all cases advisable! Thanks for the comment :)